# Azure BizTalk Transform Service API ARM Template Creation

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps, biztalk-services

I have created below ARM template for creating "BizTalk Transform Service "(API APP) which is using in Logic Apps.

```
  {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "name": "[parameters('apiapps_customertransformation_name')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "apiApp",
        "tags": {
            "packageId": "TransformService"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('apiapps_customertransformation_name')]",
            "gatewaySiteName": "[parameters('gatewayName')]",
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('svcPlanName'))]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "EMA_MicroserviceId",
                        "value": "[parameters('apiapps_customertransformation_name')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "EMA_Secret",
                        "value": "[parameters('gatewayToAPIappSecret')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "EMA_RuntimeUrl",
                        "value": "[concat('https://', parameters('gatewayName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_START_SCM_ON_SITE_CREATION",
                        "value": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.AppService/apiapps",
        "apiVersion": "2015-03-01-preview",
        "name": "[parameters('apiapps_customertransformation_name')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "APIApp"
          },
        "properties": {
            "package": {
                "id": "TransformService"
            },
            "updatePolicy": "Auto",
            "accessLevel": "PublicAnonymous",
            "host": {
                "resourceName": "[parameters('apiapps_customertransformation_name')]",
                "resourceType": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
            },
            "gateway": {
                "resourceName": "[parameters('gatewayName')]",
                "resourceType": "Microsoft.AppService/gateways"
            }

        },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('apiapps_customertransformation_name'))]"
      ]
    }
```

I am able to successfully created the API in Azure Portal, but when I try to add the Map component in Transform API. It says not found.

Can you please let me know how to enable map component?

Or is there any way to directly create a Map component while deploying ARM Template?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seem that you are trying to use the preview_V1 transform, i would suggest not to use that as it will be deprecated soon.
Try the preview_V2 "Xml Transform" function in LogicApp itself.

**Checkout this documentation to get started
[Xml Transform in LogicApps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-enterprise-integration-transform/)**

LogicApp Documentation
 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-what-are-logic-apps/

Comment: Hi Tushar, Actually I have completed all the development and it testing phase. we are deploying in the process of QA Environment. Is there any way to upgrade from V1 to V2 version?. I have also used Sql Connector Preview_v1. do I need to add that as well. If so, how do i create v2 version of SQL connector. and also how to deploy other environments using ARM template.Can you please share sample template?

Comment: @Vinoth it won't be a good idea to just change the LogicApp version from v1 to v2 there are major architecture changes also. eg. now the connectors are Microsoft managed so it is just about you deploying the LogicApp definition with the connection information for each connector. I would suggest you should spend some time to go through the new version and get acquainted with it. Checkout this jump start https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-what-are-logic-apps/

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I have found out the way to create a ARM template for creating SQL connectors. as of now, i am using v1 connectors. I will go through the URL and will implement the same in using V2 connectors